# SpriteKit how to create and transition to different scenes

Tags: sprite-kit

I have created a game with sprite kit but at the moment when the game is launched, it goes straight to the game. How can i implement different scenes like a main menu and a game over scene and transition between them either by pressing a label on the screen or by a contact during the game.

Comment: You can simply present a startup scene from your view controller. From the startup screen, you can present the game scene.

Answer (score 14):

You could try something like this. Create a new class and call it whatever you want (I called mine GameStartMenu, and make it a subclass of SKScene)

In your ViewController .m file replace MyScene with the new class name:

```
// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [GameStartMenu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

Then in your new class .m type something like this:

```
#import "GameStartMenu.h"
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation GameStartMenu

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.5 green:1.0 blue:0.5 alpha:0.0];

        NSString *nextSceneButton;
        nextSceneButton = @"Start";

        SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

        myLabel.text = nextSceneButton;
        myLabel.fontSize = 30;
        myLabel.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
        myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        myLabel.name = @"scene button";

        [self addChild:myLabel];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"scene button"]) {

        SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:3];

        MyScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        [self.view presentScene:scene transition:reveal];
    }
}

@end
```

This creates a label that when touched transitions to the new scene (MyScene). Delete whatever you need to like background color etc. Now I'm also new to programming so this could be completely the wrong way to do it but this works for me so far.

Comment: Great Answer for the last part with the sktransition. I had been looking for this.